# What is known about this conjectured symmetry in the generalized Radon-Hurwitz numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, homotopy-theory, differential-topology, vector-bundles

The ***generalized Radon-Hurwitz number*** $\rho(m, n)$ is defined as the
maximal dimension of a subspace contained in $Q_{m,n }$, the subset of all real $m\times n$ matrices $A$ which satisfy $AA^T=\lambda I_m$ for some scalar $\lambda\in\mathbb R$.

[This](http://archive.numdam.org/article/CM_1986__59_1_113_0.pdf) article gives a summary and next to the end a table of some values. Knowing that it is from 1986, chances are that by today, many gaps may have been filled. But I made a striking observation and wonder if anything is known about that. Pure inspection may lead to the following

> **Conjecture:**
> (1) For $(m,n)\in\quad[1,2^k]\quad\quad\times[2^k,2^{k+1}-1]$, we have $\quad\rho(m, n)=\rho(2^{k+1}-n, 2^{k+1}-m)$
> (2) For $(m,n)\in[2^k+1,2^{k+1}]\times[2^k,2^{k+1}-1]$, we have $\quad\rho(m, n)=\rho(3\cdot2^k-n, 3\cdot2^k-m)$.

Graphically, this means that each of the framed subsquares of the table would be symmetric w.r.t. its secondary diagonal (i.e. the colored entries). Here the red squares correspond to (1), the blue squares to (2).

[image]

Note that according to a comment on the (plain) Hurwitz-Radon numbers in [oeis A003484](http://oeis.org/A003484), for any $k\in\mathbb N$, the list of the first $2^k - 1$ terms of the diagonal sequence $\{\rho(m,m)\}_{m\in\mathbb N}$ is palindromic, which implies by induction that this symmetry is true for the next-to-main diagonals of the blue squares.

> Is there anything known about this symmetry?

***EDIT:*** In terms of subspaces, or more precisely sets of matrices, a stronger conjecture (or is it in fact equivalent?) can be formulated as follows:

> (3) Let $m\le n$ and $k=\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor$ (this corresponds to the $k$ in (1) and (2) above). Then there is (in a certain way which remains to define, maybe even in a canonical way?) an **isomorphism** $$Q_{m,n }\cong\begin{cases}  Q_{ 2\cdot2^k-n, 2\cdot2^k-m} \quad&\text{if $m\leqslant2^k$}\\Q_{3\cdot2^k-n, 3\cdot2^k-m}\quad&\text{if $m>2^k$.}\end{cases}$$